# createTextNode not keeping font style

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

So right now im working on a list that you add stuff to dynamically. So I have this code so far, this is my javascript

```
$("#textBox").keypress(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13)
    addToSticky();
});

function addToSticky() {
    if(count < 5){      
        var text = document.getElementById("textBox").value;
        var node = document.createElement("LI");
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(node);
        count = count + 1;
    }else
        hideBox("textBox");
}
```

And here is my html

```
<a href="#" class="sticky" STYLE="text-decoration: none">
    <h2 STYLE="font-size:200%; font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:10px; margin-top: 4px"> 
                Notes 
    </h2>
    <p>                 
        <ul id="list" STYLE="padding-left: 20px">
            <li> <b>Hire this guy! </b></li>
        </ul>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="textBox">               
    </p>
</a>
```

And last but not least in my css I make the < a >, < li > and my < h2 > all have the font-style set to my custom font. But however when you enter what you want to add to the list it types in the custom font but when its finally added, at the appendChild, it no longer has the custom font.

Comment: Is it, because your text is not bold?

Comment: No the actual font-style is no converting over

Comment: What do you mean by not "converting over"?

Comment: When the words are added to the list whats displayed is the first of the list, in proper font, than what i added afterwards in regular not custom font

Answer (score 1):

The first element has its text wrapped inside a bold tag, the ones which are added after it don't.

If you want to make the list items bold, the best way to do this would be to use CSS to set the font-weight property of all list item elements:

```
li {
    font-weight : bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert the following lines

```
var font = document.createElement("b");
node.appendChild(font);
```

after

```
var textnode = document.createTextNode(text)
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/1e8zzLep/

Comment: No that doesnt fix the problem, it still is only default font, but bold

Comment: In the fiddle I added, you can see, that the font is exactly the same. So there must be some more styles, or css you have defined elsewhere.